# Application with a menu for different languages

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play, multilingual

I want to make an app for android and ios which will have a main menu with 4 or 5 different languages.  Selecting a language will take the user to that menu.  I heard Apple and Android do not allow to make the same app in different languages (so you can't make an app in english, same app in spanish...etc).

My question is if all the languages are in one app and the user chooses it, will I be able to upload my app to the markets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple languages in your app, but launching two applications where the only difference is the language will not be approved by Apple.
Here is a good read on localized apps:

1. [IOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial)
2. [Android](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/)

Good luck.

Comment: As long as it makes it on the market with the way I want to do it then I'm ok with it.